# IBM.WMQ - set groupID not being set

Tags: c#, ibm-mq

I'm trying the following:

```
using IBM.WMQ;

MQMessage message = new MQMessage();
message.Write(myMessage);

message.GroupID = Encoding.UFT8.GetBytes("myGroup");

queue.Put(message);
```

The message is successfully placed on the queue but viewing the message via IBM MQ Explorer, I can see the Group ID has not been set.

Answer (score -1):

That's not how you create a message group in IBM MQ. I've only done it in Java & C code and not C#. Here is a snippet of code from IBM's ***PutGroup.java*** sample. You can find the complete PutGroup program [here](https://capitalware.com/mq_code_java.html).

```
int openOptions = MQC.MQOO_OUTPUT + MQC.MQOO_FAIL_IF_QUIESCING;
MQQueue myQueue = qMgr.accessQueue(iQueue, openOptions, null, null, null);
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
String userInput = null;

do
{
   try
   {
      userInput = br.readLine();
      if (userInput.length() > 0)
      {
         MQMessage myMessage = new MQMessage();

         myMessage.messageId     = MQC.MQMI_NONE;
         myMessage.correlationId = MQC.MQCI_NONE;
         myMessage.groupId       = MQC.MQGI_NONE;

         myMessage.writeString(userInput);
         myMessage.format = MQC.MQFMT_STRING;
         myMessage.messageFlags = MQC.MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP;

         MQPutMessageOptions pmo = new MQPutMessageOptions();
         pmo.options = MQC.MQPMO_LOGICAL_ORDER | MQC.MQPMO_SYNCPOINT;

         myQueue.put(myMessage, pmo);
         System.out.print("Group ID: ");
         dumpHexId(myMessage.groupId);
         System.out.println("-->Hit enter when done with messages for group");
         do
         {
            userInput = br.readLine();
            if (userInput.length() > 0)
            {
               myMessage.clearMessage();
               myMessage.writeString(userInput);
               myMessage.messageFlags = MQC.MQMF_MSG_IN_GROUP;
               myQueue.put(myMessage, pmo);
            }

         } while (userInput.length() > 0);
         myMessage.messageFlags = MQC.MQMF_LAST_MSG_IN_GROUP;
         userInput = "Program generated last group message";
         myMessage.clearMessage();
         myMessage.writeString(userInput);
         myQueue.put(myMessage, pmo);
         qMgr.commit();
         System.out.println("-->Group now finished");
      }
   }
   catch (MQException ex)
   {
      System.err.println("Error putting message onto queue " + ex.completionCode + " " + ex.reasonCode);
   }
   catch (IOException ex)
   {
      System.err.println("IOException");
   }
} while (userInput.length() > 0);

myQueue.close();
```

Comment: Your'e doing a "myMessage.groupId       = MQC.MQGI_NONE;" and then further down you do a "dumpHexId(myMessage.groupId);". I'm not following what's going on here. I don't have a JDE so can't check the code but it looks like this will print NULL as the groupid is not being set

Comment: The queue manager is setting the GoupID field. I'd suggest you download a JDK & play around with the sample and read about message groups in the MQ Knowledge Center. [Grouping logical messages](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=ordering-grouping-logical-messages) and [Message groups](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/latest?topic=messages-message-groups)

Comment: Thanks but as per my original post, I want to specify the group ID. Not system generated. Using using IBM.XMS, I can do a SetStringProperty("GroupID", "your_group_id") and this works fine. However I don't understand why I can't do this using IBM.WMQ.